# Create database to restore results for employee feelings poll

Tags: sql, database

My project is to make a software to ask employees individually how they feel each day, good, normal, bad. So for example, on 10/9/2012 three employees feel good, four feel normal, and two feel bad. They have the ability to say why they feel like this.

I am thinking to create one table for date, one to many, and the other one for the feelings, good, normal, bad that stores how many per day felt good/bad/ normal .

My problem is how to do the "why you feel like this" table. Each status can have many reasons.

Employees must be anonymous so I can't store each one's opinion.

Comment: How will you prevent one employee from reporting that he feels bad 18 times?

Comment: I am thinking from code behind, when submit button is clicked once, button is dimmed. Another idea is my application will use windows Authentication to determine the user, so I can limit each user to use report once.

Comment: What prevents them from coming back to the form?

Comment: cos it will be WPF not form, form will be only for the bosses, so they can see the general mood of their company, without knowing which user feels how.

Comment: @Mark I think what njk is nudging you towards is the question "How can you prevent a user submitting multiple times if you are not storing the user's ID?". The answer, by the way, is to store a salted, one-way hash of the user's id - maintaining anonymity, while allowing you to prevent multiple submissions.

Comment: There are a small number of ids, so brute forcing that would be trivial :)

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I'd use a single table with theDate, Feeling, Reason, and maybe CookieValue.  (Use a cookie to prevent one employee from feeling bad 18 times).  Each day you'd have a bunch of entries.

The boss page would then just do a select on this table, group by Date, & show the counts.  Perhaps `Select distinct feeling, count(*) as numCount where theDate = getdate() group by feeling`

---

If you really want multiple tables, then you're probably looking to implement the middle of a many-to-many join.  To do that, have one table with a primary key (pkDateTable) and theDate, a second table with a primary key (pkFeeling) and the Feeling choices, then create a 3rd table that has two foreign keys (pkDateTable, pkFeeling) and the Reason.  I wouldn't go this way (too complicated for this example), but perhaps there's more to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a little complicated, since you can't store the actual user's identifying information.  My recommendation is to do the following:

1 - Create a table for "Feelings" that just contains a list of all available feelings that a user can select (probably something like "Great", "Good", "Okay", "Not Good", "Bad" or whatever combination you would like).  Give this table a unique incrementing identity and also a varchar(25) for the description of the feeling.  So your table will look something like this:

```
Feelings
    id (int, identity)
    description (varchar(25))
```

2 - Create a table for "Users" that will contain an MD5 or SHA-2 hash of their email coalesced with a chosen password.  This way you aren't storing their actual user information.  Also give this table a unique incrementing identity.  Your usertable should look something like :

```
Users
    id (int, identity)
    userhash (varchar(64))
```

3 - Bring it all together as a relationship by creating a table which will contain Feelings.id and Users.id as foreign keys as well as a date field and a field to describe "why".  I would make it as so:

```
UserFeelings
    id (int)
    user_id (int, fkey to Users.id)
    feeling_id (int, fkey to Feelings.id)
    when (date)
    why (varchar(max))
```

As long as you make user_id + when a unique constraint then you shouldn't have any conflicts in the database and everything should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would set it up:

```
CREATE TABLE feelings (
  feeling_id tinyint PRIMARY KEY,
  feeling_type varchar(15))

INSERT INTO feelings (feeling_id, feeling_type) VALUES 
(3, 'Good'), (2, 'Normal'), (1, 'Bad')
```

By giving 'feelings' weights (3 = Good, 1 = Bad), you can calculate the overall 'mood' easier.

```
CREATE TABLE feeling_entry (
  entry_id int PRIMARY_KEY,
  entry_date date,
  entry_feeling_id tinyint))
```

This table would record the date and the `feeling_id` referencing table `feelings`.

```
CREATE TABLE feeling_entry_reason (
  entry_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  entry_reason varchar(255))
```

Adding a table for the feeling reasons is beneficial as each recorded feeling may not have a reason.

Lastly, you should have a way of tracking the user has submitted the form to prevent duplicate 'negative' feedback. Your script would simply check if an entry has been made by that user for that date. It does not correspond to an actual entry.

```
CREATE TABLE feeling_submit (
  user_id int,
  entry_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, entry_date))
```

Comment: Ok Thank you all for your awesome feedback, I will try this.